# Visual intuition for $\frac{1}{b - a} \int_{a}^{b} u(t) \ \text{d}t \in \overline{\text{co}}(u([a,b]))$

Tags: intuition, visualization, convex-hulls

> Let $u: [a,b] \to X$ to be a continuous function and $X$ a Banach space.
>   Then 
>   $$
> \frac{1}{b - a} \int_{a}^{b} u(t) \ \text{d}t \in \overline{\text{co}}(u([a,b]))
> $$
>   holds, where $\overline{\text{co}}(M) = \overline{\text{co}(M)}^{\| \cdot \|_{X}}$ is the closed convex hull for some set $M \subset X$ and 
>   $$
> \text{co}(M)
> := \left\{ \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \lambda_i x_i: N \in \mathbb{N}, \lambda_i \in [0,1], \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \lambda_i = 1, x_i \in M \ \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, N\} \right\}.
> $$

How can we visualise this result geometrically?

Comment: What kind of visualisation do you want? From the deleted answer's proof you know that it comes down to the fact that the left hand side is nothing more than a limit of a bunch of convex combinations. Is the fact that a convex combination belongs to a convex hull not intuitive enough, eg if I have 20 marbles on the floor, is it obvious that the average position is somewhere in the middle?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes, but I'd like to know how I can draw a picture to convince myself that the integral aka the area under a curve belongs to the closed convex hull. What I am trying to say is that it is clear in the discrete case as you pointed out but I want to know how ome can visualize it in the continuous case.

Comment: The center of mass of a bottle of water is somewhere in the middle

Comment: @CalvinKhor What is $u$ in this case? And a normal bottle isn't convex, right?

Comment: Well I wasn't caring about the dimension, if you want it to match exactly use a string. the center of mass is somewhere 'in the middle'(=in the convex hull). Yes, I recall my fabric softener comes in a bottle which is a (resealable) torus... And in this case (or in the case of a rubber band loop) you don't expect the mass to be in the object itself, but you can't make it go outside the convex hull

Comment: @CalvinKhor Also, how where you able to see the deleted answer? And why exactly is $\frac{\int_{a}^{b} u(t) dt}{b - a}$ the centre of mass?

Comment: It's an average of position, since it's not necessarily in the form of an integral wrt arclength, it may not be uniform density. But how else would you define a center of mass? the only other alternative in my mind would be to use the Riemann sum limit as a definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral on left-hand side (divided by $b-a$), which I denote by $\bar u$ in the visualization, can be interpreted as an average over the trajectory of $u$. I have tried to visualize it for two different trajectories in $\mathbb R^2$. In some sense, it is a *weighted* average over the points of the trajectory, since "segments" where the velocity is high get a lower weight in the average process. I tried to visualize this fact by the intermediate points, in particular in the second example, where the velocity is high in the beginning and low in the end, thereby shifting $\bar u$ to the right.
The true average would be the mean of the images of infinitely many equidistant "intermediate points" in $[a,b]$ (or, alternatively, one may think of the segments between those points).

As mentioned before, $\bar u$ being a (weighted) average over the trajectory guarantees that it lies in the closed convex hull of the trajectory

[image: visualization]